# Fitting a predictive model when I only care about the top values

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling, loss-functions

I want to build a predictive model that given a certain set of features, predicts a value ( As in regular linear regression models). But as opposed to regular least squares, 
I actually don't care about the error over all data points - I am interested only in the order of the "top" values - That is, my usage of the model is to pick the best 100 data points (with their relative order), out of 
tens of thousands, and so I only care about the predicted values of these points. Is there any way to achieve this directly through some sort of error function / Statistical procedure / Machine learning algorithm?
The problem is that sometime I improve my predictive power in terms of least squares, but that does not necessarily mean that I improved the prediction of the "top" values, since
I might be finding weights which are relevant to the vast amount of data points with low predictive values which I will not eventually use (And which I would want to eventually filter out).

Comment: It is difficult to advise. Do you want to predict what are the top 100 values (e.g. scores on some measure) or is it crucial to predict which they are (e.g. some name or descriptive text). In what sense are you trying to predict, including whether there is a time element to this? What's wrong with listing the values in order and picking off the top 100? For example, it's one thing to try to predict the 3 best times for 100 m sprint at the Olympics in 2016, but a quite a different problem to predict who the corresponding athletes will be.

Comment: In short - Yes, I want to predict what are the top 100 values and would want an error function which captures this. There is no time element to this, besides the fact that I want to learn the weights of each feature from past data, in order to predict this for future data. The problem with learning a linear model from previous data, listing the values in order and picking the best 100 - Is that it might be suboptimal in terms of the weights it learns (Since I'm interested in an error function that is different from least square).